# foldl expression not compiling due to use of literal

Tags: haskell

I have the following use of foldl which is erroring:

```
elementAt :: [a] -> Int -> a
elementAt [] x = error "No empty lists for element-at"
elementAt xs x = foldl(\acc (a, b) -> if(b == x) then a else acc) 0 $ zip xs [0..]
```

When I try and compile I get this error:

> exercises.hs:8:67: error:
>       * No instance for (Num a) arising from the literal `0'
>         Possible fix:
>           add (Num a) to the context of
>             the type signature for:
>               elementAt :: [a] -> Int -> a
>       * In the second argument of`foldl', namely `0'
>         In the expression:
>           foldl (\ acc (a, b) -> if (b == x) then a else acc) 0
>         In the expression:
>           foldl (\ acc (a, b) -> if (b == x) then a else acc) 0
>           $ zip xs [0 .. ] Failed, modules loaded: none.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you don't find the element, the result of your function is `0`. That only makes sense if you're working with a list of numbers. If you pass in a list of strings and then return either a string from the list or the number `0`, that'd be a clear type error.

So your function only works with lists of numbers and your type signature must reflect that by adding a `Num a` constraint.

However a better solution would be to not use `0` as the default value and use a `Maybe` instead. That way you don't have to restrict yourself to lists of numbers.